# How to supply parameters to autocomplete function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Below is my autocomplete function that's build on top of jQuery.ui. It works perfectly fine. All I want to do is with this line: `var targetItem = $("#subject");`. Currently as you can see, assign `$("#subject")` to the `'targetItem'` variable in the autocomplete function.

But I want value assign to `'targetItem'` variable based on the 'keyup' event of textbox.In short, I tried something like this:

```
var target;
   var targetItem2;
    $("input[type=text]").on("keyup",function()
        {
            target = this.id;
            alert(target);
           targetItem2 = $("#"+target);
        });
```

I placed it above the autocomplete function and then assign 'targetItem2' to the 'targetItem' variable but it doesn't get the value passed.

Is there a way to do something with this function so that value can be assign based on keyup event or better anyway I can pass parameters to the autocomplete function instead?

HTML

```
 <div class="ui-widget">
                 <input id="subject" type="text" name="subject" value="" placeholder="Subject" class="1"/>
  </div>
```

jQuery

```
$.widget('custom.mcautocomplete', $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderItem: function(ul, item) {
        var t = '',
            result = '';

        $.each(this.options.columns, function(index, column) {

            t += '<span style="float:left;min-width:' + column.minWidth + ';">' + item[column.valueField ? column.valueField : index] + '</span>'
        });

        result = $('<li></li>')
            .data('ui-autocomplete-item', item)
            .append('<a class="mcacAnchor">' + t + '<div style="clear: both;"></div></a>')
            .appendTo(ul);
        return result;
    }
});
 //ajax starts
    var targetItem = $("#subject");//want to assign value form supplied parameter
    $("document").ready(function(){       
    var data = {
      "action": "test"
    };
    data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "store2.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
      //$("#showPlace").html("<br />JSON: " + data );
     // alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["json"]);
    // alert(data);
      // console.log(data);
        var columns = [{
        name: 'level',
        minWidth: '200px'},
        {
        name: 'subject',
        minWidth: '70px'},
        {
        name: 'catid',
        minWidth: '70px'}
        ],

        colors = data;
        var selectThis=targetItem.attr("class");//textbox class determines which item in array to select
        var valueV=targetItem.attr("value");
        targetItem.mcautocomplete({
        showHeader: true,
        columns: columns,
        source: colors,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            // Set the input box's value
            this.value = (ui.item ? ui.item[selectThis] : '');

            //search for nearest value

            // Set the output div's value
            $('#show_subject') && $('#show_subject').text(ui.item ? ('Subject = ' + ui.item[selectThis]) : 'Select a subject');
            return false;
         }
       });
            }
          });

      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually just use `this` when you're in an event instead of trying to pull the id and build a selector to use. You'll just have to wrap it in jQuery. Here's an example that shows your code and an example with `this`. Take a look at your browser's log to see the difference. Both should work as you expect though.

https://jsfiddle.net/m7nt39x0/3/

Comment: I want to be able to get the following output outside the keyup function: "console.log(targetItem1);"

Comment: I've updated the fiddle. creating the variable outside of the scope of the keyup function will let you use it elsewhere.